# How to accept only a specified pattern from JTextField?

Tags: java, regex, swing

I want a `JTextField` to accept only my specified pattern. "12ABCDE1234A1A1"

NOTE- that pattern can have any digit and alphabet.

```
JTextField t17 = new JTextField();
final String match ="(\\d\\d)-([a-zA-z]{5})-(\\d\\d\\d\\d)-([a-zA-z]{1})- 
(\\d)-([a-zA-z]{1})-(\\d)+$";
Pattern pt = Pattern.compile(match);
final Matcher mt =pt.matcher(t17.getText());
t17.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent arg0) {
        if(mt.matches()){
            lblPin.setText("verified");
        }else{
            JOptionPane op = new JOptionPane();
            op.showMessageDialog(iff, "INVALID GST NUMBER");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: 1) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! 2) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant. 3) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 4) **See also, [`JFormattedTextField`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html).**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, i solved the above problem using JformattedtextField.

```
MaskFormatter mask = new      MaskFormatter ("##?????####?#?# "):                    JformattedtextField tf = new        JformattedtextField (mask);
```

That's all.. no need of if else

Answer (score 0):

After you enter tekst to your `JTextField`, validate it's text against this pattern:

```
^\\d{2}[A-Z]{5}\\d{4}([A-Z]\\d){2}$
```

And call `t17.getText()` inside `FocusAdapter` method, so you'll get currently entered text.

You can try this in Java code:

```
public class JavaFiddle
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    java.util.regex.Pattern pt = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("^\\d{2}[A-Z]{5}\\d{4}([A-Z]\\d){2}$");
    java.util.regex.Matcher mt = pt.matcher("12ABCDE1234A1A1");
    if(mt.matches()){
      System.out.println("success");
    }else{
      System.out.println("failuire");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Single backwards slash or double backwards slash

Comment: Single slash gives error... 

And i am getting the entered text. But if else is not working.  It always gives "invalid gst number"

Comment: double slash just don't give a escape sequence error...


Rest is.. code note working